# Why is bash adding spaces and stretching out filenames in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, arch-linux

My Arch Linux laptop is creating some strange output when using bash. It puts spaces between characters and stretches out files names. I’ve tried to remove/reinstall bash-completion but nothing changed. Does anyone know any solution or workaround for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal expects to use a monospace font, but you have used a proportional font. So when the cursor moves right or left, it moves by a fixed amount each time, rather than proprtionally based on whatever character was on the screen. Thus your columns are not lined up and moving backward ends up in the wrong place.

To fix the problem, change the terminal font to a monospaced font.

Comment: Oh, completely forgot about fonts in Terminal. However, font was already set to "monospace"  but switching it to any other and setting monospace again solved my issue.

Comment: Something was wrong, then, because the font in your screenshot is definitely _not_ monospace! :)

Comment: Maybe the system just doesn't have any fonts that "monospace" is aliased to? (By default it corresponds to "DejaVu Sans Mono".)